# Allowing admin-ajax.php to receive "application/json" instead of "x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: admin, ajax, javascript, json

I'm using AngularJS's `$http` function to send my payload to WordPress's `admin-ajax.php` subsystem, but it seems the latter only accepts `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, instead of the `application/json` supplied by Angular.

I know [there are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19270196/467760) of making $http function more like `$.post()`, but this is nonsensical — why transform a bunch of JSON data into a form when it's already JSON?

To that end — **is there any way of instructing `admin-ajax` to consume type as `application/JSON` instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> it seems the latter only accepts x-www-form-urlencoded

That's not completely true.

WordPress `admin-ajax.php` takes the action from `$_REQUEST['action']` and `$_REQUEST` is equal to:

```
array_merge($_POST, $_GET);
```

But what many people don't realize is that `$_GET` in PHP is **not** the data was sent to page using HTTP GET method, in fact, you can use whatever HTTP method (POST, PUT, DELETE...)
and whatever content type, and `$_GET` will always contain data you pass to url query string.

It means that if you send a request to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=awesome_action` "awesome_action" is always reached, no matter the HTTP method you use and no matter the HTTP content type.

In short, if you are able to send the *action* argument with the url, you can use `admin-ajax.php` to send whatever JSON data and whatever HTTP method, then is **your** problem handle them.

However that's quite easy using `php://input` stream.

### Example

First of all I'll write a function that uses curl to send an HTTP request with JSON content type (because I don't want to write Angular code here):

```
/**
 * @param string $url  Url for for the request
 * @param string $data JSON-encoded data to send
 */
function mySendJson($url, $data)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); // PUT HTTP method
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',           // JSON content type
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
    );
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Pretty easy.

Now, just for testing purpose, I'll put a function in frontend footer that sends a HTTP request with JSON content type using the function above, and expects some JSON back:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function() {

    $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=json-test');

    // some dummy json data
    $data = array("name" => "Giuseppe", "country" => "Italy");
    $json = json_encode($data);

    // Using curl we simulate send HTTP request with json content type
    // in your case is Angular that perform the request
    $json_response = mySendJson($ajax_url, $json);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($json_response, true));
    echo '</pre>';
});
```

Now, when `admin-ajax.php` is requested it will look for any callback attached to `'wp_ajax_json-test'` hook (or `'wp_ajax_nopriv_json-test'`) for non-logged users.

Let's add a custom function to those hooks:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_json-test', 'myWpAjaxTest');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_json-test', 'myWpAjaxTest');
```

The function `myWpAjaxTest()` will be called by WordPress when the HTTP request with JSON content type is sent to `admin-ajax.php`.

Let's write it:

```
function myWpAjaxTest() {
    // Retrieve HTTP method
    $method = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Retrieve JSON payload
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    // do something intersting with data,
    // maybe something different depending on HTTP method

    wp_send_json(array(  // send JSON back
      'method'        => $method,
      'data_received' => $data
    ));
}
```

Thanks to `php://input` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)) last function

- parses the JSON data that was sent to `admin-ajax.php`
- manipulates it
- sends back a JSON response (because `wp_send_json` [uses json content type](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/bc55996a0b2a927c05974ceed04bde319b70d631/wp-includes/functions.php#L2786))

As final result, if you look at theme footer, you'll find something like:

```
Array
(
    [method] => PUT
    [data_received] => Array
        (
            [name] => Giuseppe
            [country] => Italy
        )

)
```

Comment: Epic. Win. Possibly one of the best answers I've received on WP.SE. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

`admin-ajax.php` was designed to work against jQuery, most likely if you do not make the conversion on the JS site you will have to do it on the server side to make it work. Instead  you can add your own "end point" that can process json. The biggest problem with this approach is the query that WP runs on "front end" urls.